# How to prevent "Provided document path must not be null." Firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when i want to onBackPressed move to previous activity (ViewData.class), but i can't do that. Is there a solution to fix the problem? The problem is :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:906)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:103)
    at id.MuhammadRafi.StockCount.ViewData.onStart(ViewData.java:200)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
```

ViewData.java :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    documentID = getIntent().getStringExtra("documentID");

    collectionReference.document(documentID).collection("Products").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                itemsList.clear();

                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    Items items = documentSnapshot.toObject(Items.class);
                    itemsList.add(items);

                    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent moveView = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, ViewData.class);
    startActivity(moveView);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'll do it next time. Thanks for attention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go back to a previous activity, no need to

```
startActivity(moveView);
finish();
```

in your `onBackPressed()`. what you are doing there is starting another instance of that activity and sending the data you want to send back.

Instead do `startActivityForResult()` in your `ViewData.class` and in your `onBackPressed()` in `MainActivity`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent moveView = getIntent();
    //Here your can add whatever values you want to send back to your activity
    moveView.putExtra("some_key",value)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,moveView);
    finish();
}
```

then in your `ViewData.class` override `onActivityResult()` there is where you will retrieve the data sent by the current activity. See [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)
The issue you are having with Firestore is that you haven't initialized with a proper path, maybe due to that you are starting a new instance of `ViewData.class`

Comment: By the way, moveView.putExtra in ViewData.class has been declared in the RecyclerView class. I just want to go back to the previous activity from MainActivity,class to ViewData.class. I think the error is ViewData.class requires documentID when i click onBackPressed

Comment: @Mr.Robot by the way, did you check the link I posted in my answer?, Did you understand the part when I said that you are not returning to your previous activity but instead you are creating a NEW instance?

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null

above error is caused by this line:

```
documentID = getIntent().getStringExtra("documentID");
```

here documentID is null.

And to get back into previous activity just remove onBackPressed method or override it as:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And in your current activity's onCreate() add this line to make navigation back icon work -

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Example : I have 3 activities. When i change onBackPressed like that on activity 3, it was return to activity 1 not return to activity 2

Comment: when you start activity 3 from activity 2 don't use finish();